# PayPal API orders not being completed

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'd like to ask you for advice please.

We have this PayPal API enabled website store and works fine but we are getting some higher number of interrupted orders. Most of them go through fine but strange problem is that some customers report they cannot complete the transaction, being redirected away from the paypal payment page.

We tried in Sandbox and also on live site but we can't manage to replicate any problems like this. Each transaction goes trough fine.

Has anyone come across this before, have we missed something?

Comment: Are you logging API requests and responses, at least for failures, so we can see what's happening in those cases?

Comment: just did some more testing and it seems that on first attempt you get this error: (when using cards)

your paypal account is not eligible we’re sorry, this credit product is not offered in the country/region where your paypal account is located.

and if you try again it works and transaction is completed.